# Spring Gateway OAuth - Full URL on redirect

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

We are using Spring Gateway Service for Security (OAuth2). Redirect for login is responded as relative path Eg: Location: /oauth2/authorization/client1.

How do we enforce to respond a fully url on redirects (always, not just for login)

Eg: Location: https://example.com/oauth2/authorization/google

Any help please.

Comment: can you share configurations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I got it working - at least for auth entry and auth success urls.

1. Create a class by extending DefaultServerRedirectStrategy and implement sendRedirect method by adding baseUrl (schema, host and port) to the uri param.
2. Create an instance of RedirectServerAuthenicationSuccessHandler and set redirectStrategy created in step 1.
3. In ServerHttpSecurity.oauth2Login() set authentionSuccessHandler created in step 2
4. Like in Step 2 and Step 3, create an instance of RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint, set redirectStragey and add it to the ServerHttpSecurity.exceptionHandling()

Hope this helps to anyone looking for a solution.

Comment: Any other solution, please post it.